# Download image not being displayed iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, request, nsurl

I'm trying to download images and display them based on different conditions. The code worked if I was to simply download the images in the main thread, but I am trying to download them through the back end now.

My console is clean, so I'm not getting any errors - yet my images are not being displayed? This is my first attempt at doing back end image downloading and also doing swift as I come from objective-c.

Could someone please look at the code below and let me know what the problem is?

```
//FizzBuzz Image Download
weak var fizzBuzzImage: UIImage!
let fizzBuzzString = "https://emkaydeum.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/fizzbuzz.png"
var fizzBuzzURL:NSURL!

//Fizz Image Download
weak var fizzImage: UIImage!
let fizzString = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/b/b0/Fizz_Render.png/revision/latest?cb=20151205185848"
var fizzURL:NSURL!

//Buzz Image Download
weak var buzzImage: UIImage!
let buzzString = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/b/bc/Buzz_Disney_INFINITY_Render.png/revision/latest?cb=20140605182818"
var buzzURL:NSURL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fizzBuzzURL = NSURL(string: fizzBuzzString)
    fizzURL = NSURL(string: fizzString)
    buzzURL = NSURL(string: buzzString)
}

@IBAction func checkTextField(_ sender: UITextView){

    enteredValue = userInput.text

    let checkIfEmpty = userInput.text?.isEmpty

    if (checkIfEmpty == false) {
    let multipleOf3:Int = Int(enteredValue)!%3
    let multipleOf5:Int = Int(enteredValue)!%5

        if (multipleOf3 == 0 && multipleOf5 == 0) {
            fizzBuzz.text = "FizzBuzz"
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (fizzBuzzURL as URL), completionHandler: {(fizzBuzzData, resp, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil && fizzBuzzData != nil){
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                        self.displayImage.image = UIImage(data: fizzBuzzData!)
                    })
                }
                }).resume()}
        else if (multipleOf5 == 0){
            fizzBuzz.text = "Buzz"
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (buzzURL as URL), completionHandler: {(buzzData, resp, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil && buzzData != nil){
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                        self.displayImage.image = UIImage(data: buzzData!)
                })
                }
                }).resume()}
        else if (multipleOf3 == 0){
            fizzBuzz.text = "Fizz"
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (fizzURL as URL), completionHandler: {(fizzData, resp, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil && fizzData != nil){
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                        self.displayImage.image = UIImage(data: fizzData!)
                })
                }
                }).resume()}
        else {
            fizzBuzz.text = "Incorrect Value"
            displayImage.image = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this condition you have added if (error != nil && fizzBuzzData != nil)  You are checking error must not be nil & data must not be nil. Write it as if (error == nil && fizzBuzzData != nil)

Comment: Don't use `NSURL` in Swift, use its native counterpart, `URL`. Did you check if your if clauses are actually hit?

Comment: Doesn't that mean if there is no error, and the data source is not nil, then it should continue the function with the response?

Comment: as per your code, that means error object has some value.And why are using OperationQueue? You can use mainqueue direclty if you find that main thread is busy somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Gagan! That fixed it. Now you've explained it - it does make sense. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check for your IF conditions. You have written

```
if (error != nil && fizzBuzzData != nil){
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                        self.displayImage.image = UIImage(data: fizzBuzzData!)
                    })
                }
```

which never executed. Please make it as below

```
 if (error == nil && fizzBuzzData != nil){
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation ({
                        self.displayImage.image = UIImage(data: fizzBuzzData!)
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

set

uiimageview contentMode is scaleAspectFill

and clipsToBounds true